# Why is Visual Studio Code saying my code in unreachable after using the Pandas concat function?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

[image: Koda Ulaşılamıyor -> Code is unreachable]

> Koda Ulaşılamıyor -> Code is unreachable

Visual Studio code is graying out my code and saying it is unreachable after I used `pd.concat()`.  The IDE seems to run smoothly but it's disturbing and I want my colorful editor back.

How do I disable the editor graying out my code without changing the current language?

Comment: if you comment the line with `pd.concat` you get the colors back, try to determine why PyLance things `pd.concat` is a non-returning function, disable semantic highlighting in the settings

Comment: if you create a small example with the behavior create an issue at the PyLance repo

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual code in a code block.   or add it so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: Please make sure to par it down to just enough code that makes it exhibit the greying out.

Comment: Note this behavior is supposed to indicate unreachable code - i.e. if you add a line containing `exit(0)` then any code after this line will be unreachable and hence will be greyed out. And as the answer below states there's a bug in python-stubs which (incorrectly) indicates implies unreachable code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug currently existing in `pandas-stubs`.

The matching overload of `concat` in pandas-stubs currently returns **Never**.

According to [this suggestion in Pylance github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5630), you could work around the pandas-stubs issue by commenting out the Never overload in `...\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2024.3.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\reshape\concat.pyi`.

```
@overload
def concat(
    objs: Iterable[None] | Mapping[HashableT1, None],
    *,
    axis: Axis = ...,
    join: Literal["inner", "outer"] = ...,
    ignore_index: bool = ...,
    keys: Iterable[HashableT2] = ...,
    levels: Sequence[list[HashableT3] | tuple[HashableT3, ...]] = ...,
    names: list[HashableT4] = ...,
    verify_integrity: bool = ...,
    sort: bool = ...,
    copy: bool = ...,
) -> Never: ...
```

Comment: Relevant pandas-stubs issue is here
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/888

Comment: This got fixed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/pull/890 so the `main` version should work fine. In the meantime, if you are going to monkey patch, might as well use their fix for it (see their pull).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because there is an overloaded method signature in `pandas-stubs` which states that giving an `Iterable[None]` will always throw an exception. Instead it only accepts `Iterable[Series]` or `Iterable[DataFrame]`. VSCode's static analysis doesn't check whether this is true, of course, so it falsely claims there is unreachable code.

There is some debate about who's responsibility it is to make this work as expected ([see github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/888)), but I'd like to offer an easy solution that doesn't involve monkey-patching the stubs, and should always work.

If you add type hints to reassure VSCode that the input will be one of the accepted types, then it won't think that the program will crash.

In your case, the problem is that sort_values says it will return `Any`. So, you can fix that by just add type hints to the preceding variables:

```py
sorted_excel_file_1: pd.DataFrame = df.iloc[:82].sort_values(by='H-arm', ascending=True)
sorted_excel_file_2: pd.DataFrame = df.iloc[82:].sort_values(by='H-arm', ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```py
sorted_excel_files:list[pd.DataFrame] = [sorted_excel_file_1, sorted_excel_file_2]
sorted_excel_file = pd.concat(excel_files)
```

Comment: You really should elaborate on what you did here to make it clear to others. This is such a simple fix and much easier than monkey-patching etc. Basically, the type hints on the list to be concatenated makes the whole "unreachable" issue go away

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be corrected in your code by defining the expected variable type with typing:

```
import typing

myvariable: typing.Iterable[list]

# add your code base here for sorted_excel_file_1 and sorted_excel_file_2

myvariable = [sorted_excel_file_1, sorted_excel_file_2]
sorted_excel_file = pd.concat(myvariable)

# continue your code base here
```